# How to get data from ASP.NET Core MVC using Ajax with Datatables?

Tags: datatables, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I have this problem when trying to pass a string parameter from DataTable with Ajax to an ASP.NET MVC controller.

I have a problem when I using ASP.NET Core MVC with datatable and ajax. Please kindly help me correct, Thanks

My code - controller:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public JsonResult GetList()
    {
        List<Cusaccount> cusaccountlist = new List<Cusaccount>();

        try
        {
            cusaccountlist = _dal.GetAllCusaccount();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            TempData["errorMessage"] = ex.Message;
        }

        return Json(cusaccountlist);
    }
```

View file:

```
<table id="bindDataTable" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Account</th>
            <th>Plate No</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Branch</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Account</th>
            <th>Plate No</th>
            <th>Customer</th>
            <th>Branch</th>
            <th>Type</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#bindDataTable').DataTable(
                {
                    ajax: {
                        url: '/Cusaccount/GetList',
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        type: 'GET',
                        success: function (result) {
                            console.log(result);
                        }
                    },
                    
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    filter: true,
                    columns: [{ data: 'acP_ID' },
                            { data: 'acP_NAME' },
                            { data: 'acP_ADD' },
                            { data: 'cuS_NAME_LOCAL' },
                            { data: 'cbR_NAME_LOCAL' },
                            { data: 'viC_TYPE' },
                            {
                                data: null, render: function (data, type, row) {
                            return "<div class='btn-group btn-group-sm'><a href='/Cusaccount/Edit/" + data.acP_ID + "' class='btn btn-primary'>Edit</a><a href='/Cusaccount/Delete/" + data.acP_ID + "' class='btn btn-danger'>Delete</a></div>";
                                }
                            }
                    ]
                }
            );
        });
```

All data come to Json, but on my table don't get anything. please help me correct my problem.

Thanks a lot, I will appreciate any advice.

Comment: Is the result correct in browser console?

Comment: The result is correct json format in browser console, but not shows in Table view